# Parsing a string to find next delimiter - Processing

Tags: string, parsing, processing

So the idea here is that I'm taking a .csv into a string and each value needs to be stored into a variable. I am unsure how to properly parse a string to do this.

My idea is a function that looks like

```java
final char delim = ',';

int nextItem(String data, int startFrom) {
    if (data.charAt(startFrom) != delim) {
        return data.charAt(startFrom)
    } else {
        return nextItem(data, startFrom + 1);
    }
}
```

so if I passed it something like

```java
    nextItem("45,621,9", 0);
```

it would **return 45**

and if I passed it

```java
    nextItem("45,621,9", 3);
```

it would **return 621**

I'm not sure if I have that setup properly to be recursive, but I could also use a For loop I suppose, only real stipulation is I can't use the Substring method.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use recursion for a matter that can be easily done iteratively. Recursion is expensive in terms of stack and calling frames: A very long string could produce a StackOverflowError.

I suggest you take a look to standard method [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) of `java.lang.String`:

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is Regular Expressions.
You can seperate the words considering comma ',' as delimeter

**Code**

```
String[] nextItem(String data) {
    String[] words=data.split(",");  
    return words;     
}
```

This will return an array of strings that is the words in your input string. Then you can use the array in anyway you need.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Processing comes with a `split()` function that does exactly what you're describing.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/split_.html):

```java
String men = "Chernenko,Andropov,Brezhnev";
String[] list = split(men, ',');
// list[0] is now "Chernenko", list[1] is "Andropov"...
```

Behind the scenes it's using the `String#split()` function like [H. Sodi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373735/873165), but you should just use this function instead of defining your own.